# MySQL column sorting issue using derived tables with union

Tags: mysql, sql, union

Looking for a little help on this query. I'm trying to sort the results using the p.timer column in descending order. The error is `Every derived table must have its own alias` so I believe the issue is that the clubs table needs an alias, but not sure if that's the problem?

Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction on this.

```
select *
from (
    SELECT p.id,p.Display_Title,p.industry,p.location,p.timer,p.club_post,i.name,l.city,l.StateABBR, 1 as Rank
    FROM `names` as p
    INNER JOIN `clubs` as g ON p.club_post = '1,3,4,5,6'
    INNER JOIN places as l ON l.id = p.location
    INNER JOIN workforce as i ON i.id = p.industry
    WHERE p.status = '1' AND p.status_1 = '1' AND p.category  = '1'
    ORDER BY p.timer DESC LIMIT 0,1)
UNION (
    SELECT p.id,p.Display_Title,p.industry,p.location,p.timer,p.club_post,i.name,l.city,l.StateABBR, 2 as Rank
    FROM `names` as p
    INNER JOIN `clubs` as g ON p.club_post = '2'
    INNER JOIN places as l ON l.id = p.location
    INNER JOIN workforce as i ON i.id = p.industry
    WHERE p.status = '1' AND p.status_1 = '1' AND p.category  = '1'
    ORDER BY p.timer DESC LIMIT 0,1)
UNION (
    SELECT p.id,p.Display_Title,p.industry,p.location,p.timer,p.club_post,i.name,l.city,l.StateABBR, 3 as Rank
    FROM `names` as p
    INNER JOIN `clubs` as g ON p.club_post = '10'
    INNER JOIN places as l ON l.id = p.location
    INNER JOIN workforce as i ON i.id = p.industry
    WHERE p.status = '1' AND p.status_1 = '1' AND p.category  = '1,2'
    ORDER BY p.timer DESC LIMIT 0,1)
UNION (SELECT p.id,p.Display_Title,p.industry,p.location,p.timer,p.club_post,i.name,l.city,l.StateABBR, 4 as Rank
    FROM `names` as p
    INNER JOIN `clubs` as g ON p.club_post = '11'
    INNER JOIN places as l ON l.id = p.location
    INNER JOIN workforce as i ON i.id = p.industry
    WHERE p.status = '1' AND p.status_1 = '1' AND p.category  = '1,2'
    ORDER BY p.timer DESC LIMIT 0,1)
UNION (SELECT p.id,p.Display_Title,p.industry,p.location,p.timer,p.club_post,i.name,l.city,l.StateABBR, 5 as Rank
    FROM `names` as p
    INNER JOIN `clubs` as g ON p.club_post = '7'
    INNER JOIN places as l ON l.id = p.location
    INNER JOIN workforce as i ON i.id = p.industry
    WHERE p.status = '1' AND p.status_1 = '1' AND p.category  = '1'
    ORDER BY p.timer DESC LIMIT 0,1)
UNION (SELECT p.id,p.Display_Title,p.industry,p.location,p.timer,p.club_post,i.name,l.city,l.StateABBR, 6 as Rank
    FROM `names` as p INNER JOIN `clubs` as g ON p.club_post = '1,2,3,4,5,6'
    INNER JOIN places as l ON l.id = p.location
    INNER JOIN workforce as i ON i.id = p.industry
    WHERE p.status = '1' AND p.status_1 = '1' AND p.category  = '2'
    ORDER BY p.timer DESC LIMIT 0,1)
ORDER BY rank,p.timer DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

Comment: At the very end of the query, try changing this...  ORDER BY p.timer DESC LIMIT 0,1) ORDER BY rank,... to this... ORDER BY p.timer DESC LIMIT 0,1)x ORDER BY rank,

Comment: Thanks -- I changed the end to  `DESC LIMIT 0,1) x ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 0, 5` but still get the every table must have its own alias error?

Comment: Well maybe try giving every table an alias just put x1, x2, x3 after every closing parenthesis. Of course this kind of query is often indicative of poor design, but I guess you don't want to hear that.

Comment: @Strawberry, actually I'd would. We were asked for this specifically, but if there's a more efficient way to achieve similar results any advice would be great, even just for my own knowledge. We're going to cache the results  so that should help mitigate the issue too.

Comment: OK, well for your own knowledge, see 'normalization' then! I won't pretend that I understand exactly what you're trying to do but all the same, I suspect that there's scope for optimization here.

Comment: Will do. Much obliged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UNION is used wrong in your query. Here is the correct usage, even though the query is ugly.

```
select * from (
    SELECT p.id,p.Display_Title,p.industry,p.location,p.timer,p.club_post,i.name,l.city,l.StateABBR, 1 as Rank
    FROM `names` as p
    INNER JOIN `clubs` as g ON p.club_post = '1,3,4,5,6'
    INNER JOIN places as l ON l.id = p.location
    INNER JOIN workforce as i ON i.id = p.industry
    WHERE p.status = '1' AND p.status_1 = '1' AND p.category  = '1'
    ORDER BY p.timer DESC LIMIT 0,1
UNION
    SELECT p.id,p.Display_Title,p.industry,p.location,p.timer,p.club_post,i.name,l.city,l.StateABBR, 2 as Rank
    FROM `names` as p
    INNER JOIN `clubs` as g ON p.club_post = '2'
    INNER JOIN places as l ON l.id = p.location
    INNER JOIN workforce as i ON i.id = p.industry
    WHERE p.status = '1' AND p.status_1 = '1' AND p.category  = '1'
    ORDER BY p.timer DESC LIMIT 0,1
UNION
    SELECT p.id,p.Display_Title,p.industry,p.location,p.timer,p.club_post,i.name,l.city,l.StateABBR, 3 as Rank
    FROM `names` as p
    INNER JOIN `clubs` as g ON p.club_post = '10'
    INNER JOIN places as l ON l.id = p.location
    INNER JOIN workforce as i ON i.id = p.industry
    WHERE p.status = '1' AND p.status_1 = '1' AND p.category  = '1,2'
    ORDER BY p.timer DESC LIMIT 0,1
UNION
    SELECT p.id,p.Display_Title,p.industry,p.location,p.timer,p.club_post,i.name,l.city,l.StateABBR, 4 as Rank
    FROM `names` as p
    INNER JOIN `clubs` as g ON p.club_post = '11'
    INNER JOIN places as l ON l.id = p.location
    INNER JOIN workforce as i ON i.id = p.industry
    WHERE p.status = '1' AND p.status_1 = '1' AND p.category  = '1,2'
    ORDER BY p.timer DESC LIMIT 0,1
UNION
    SELECT p.id,p.Display_Title,p.industry,p.location,p.timer,p.club_post,i.name,l.city,l.StateABBR, 5 as Rank
    FROM `names` as p
    INNER JOIN `clubs` as g ON p.club_post = '7'
    INNER JOIN places as l ON l.id = p.location
    INNER JOIN workforce as i ON i.id = p.industry
    WHERE p.status = '1' AND p.status_1 = '1' AND p.category  = '1'
    ORDER BY p.timer DESC LIMIT 0,1
UNION
    SELECT p.id,p.Display_Title,p.industry,p.location,p.timer,p.club_post,i.name,l.city,l.StateABBR, 6 as Rank
    FROM `names` as p INNER JOIN `clubs` as g ON p.club_post = '1,2,3,4,5,6'
    INNER JOIN places as l ON l.id = p.location
    INNER JOIN workforce as i ON i.id = p.industry
    WHERE p.status = '1' AND p.status_1 = '1' AND p.category  = '2'
    ORDER BY p.timer DESC LIMIT 0,1
) subtable
ORDER BY rank,p.timer DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

Comment: Agreed, but really appreciate the help. Running into an error though at:  `two UNION ( SELECT p.id` even though everything looks right?

Comment: Sorry I realized over lunch that my initial answer was wrong. I've updated.

Comment: Hm, I wonder if it would be possible over lunch to devise a test that confirmed the veracity of that statement. ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow

Comment: @JoeFrambach -- getting an incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY error. I removed the ending so I think that's from the `ORDER BY p.timer DESC LIMIT 0,1` in each select?

Comment: @jsuissa apparently ORDER BY isn't allowed in UNIONs? That doesn't sound right

Comment: Strange -- shot in the dark, could it have to do with the backticks? Are they needed on all table names like places and workforce?

Comment: No that does not seem to be the problem. ORDER BY is not allowed in UNIONs.

Comment: You earlier edits to my question basically solved the problem. Once I replaced the ending with this it worked  `ORDER BY timer DESC LIMIT 0, 5 ` Thanks everyone for the help.